# Is there a deburr function like lodash one for angular or pure javascript/typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Lodash has this awesome function https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#deburr

> Deburrs string by converting Latin-1 Supplement and Latin Extended-A letters to basic Latin letters and removing combining diacritical marks.
>
> _.deburr('déjà vu');
>   // => 'deja vu'

That's the only one that makes me use lodash as external lib within my application.

So I would like a function like that using javascript/typescript only and/or angular.

I couldn't find anything similar.

Do you have some function for that?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a built-in function in either Angular or JavaScript.

However, it looks like that function is exported as a standalone package in NPM: [lodash.deburr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.deburr).

Comment: Can also be loaded with `npm install lodash --save-dev` and then `var _ = { deburr: require("lodash/deburr") };`

Comment: @mhodges Indeed. I think in his case though, it sounded like he wanted to avoid the whole `lodash` package and just have that one function.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Although, it will just download lodash locally - it won't go up on your web server or get loaded into your pages (which is what I thikn the OP wants to avoid). So it has the same effect, but also allows you to access more modules individually in the future without having to `npm install` anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an vanilla one-liner using [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize):

```js
const deburr = str => str.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');

deburr('déjà vu'); // => 'deja vu'
```

---

NOTE: Not all special characters are deburred:

Unicode: `Æ Ð Ø Þ ß æ ð ø þ Đ đ Ħ ħ ı Ĳ ĳ ĸ Ŀ ŀ Ł ł ŉ Ŋ ŋ Œ œ Ŧ ŧ ſ`

Lodash deburr: `Ae D O Th ss ae d o th D d H h i IJ ij k L l L l 'n N n Oe oe T t ss`

---

More info at:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511463/3841188

References: [github.com/cedmax](https://github.com/cedmax) - https://github.com/cedmax/youmightnotneed/pull/197